# Lotus Notes 8.5 client hide action button

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I am having problems hiding an action button in a view.  We recently upgraded to 8.5 and the method I used to use no longer works.  I used to be able to create a role in the acl. Then add this formula to the action button properties "Hide action if formula is true".  This is the formula @IsNotMember("[StatusUpdate]";@UserRoles)

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct formula.  `@UserRoles` returns a list of strings containing the roles for the current user surrounded by brackets, as in `"[Admin]":"[Manager]":"[User]"`

It "smells" like a bug, but perhaps there is a workaround.

I would create a simple form with a computed field to show the user's roles, and make sure they are set correctly and calculating correctly.

If so, then create a new role in the ACL, say TestRole, and set yourself to that role. Create an entirely new button on the form and set the hide/when formula to `@IsMember("[TestRole]"; @UserRoles);`  Make sure the button does not appear for you.

If all this works fine then perhaps there's some minor corruption in the database within the roles or design elements themselves, and recreating them from scratch might clear that up.  Try deleting the role, and the button, and creating them again.  (I realize this is a little far-fetched, but it wouldn't be the first time I fixed a odd problem in Lotus Notes this way.)

I would also delete the icon from the Notes workspace (assuming that still exists in 8.5?) and compact the workspace as well.  I know in Notes 6 that cleared a lot of the locally cached design elements that were often the cause of strange behavior.